# How can I use 2 Tp4056 as protection circuit for diy 2s li ion battery?

Tags: lithium-ion, protection, undervoltage, over-discharge, bms

Hi I want to use 2 Tp4056 modules as over-discharge protection circuit for my DIY 2s li ion battery pack.
Those will not be used for charging! hence will not share input! The load is an arduino nano that is going to control a small dc motor and a servo!

Is it a viable option or should I use some other method for the same.

[image: 2s li ion over discharge protection]

Comment: Would you like to use this solution because you already have the modules? Maybe it would be a better approach to use a 2S (for two batteries) Module for this application. For example, look at the "HX-2S-D01" Module.

Comment: Yes! I have quite a few of these modules! So I will prefer these modules over the rest!